# How to check if the installed Anaconda is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: python, ipython, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64, conda

A few weeks ago, to dabble in IPython notebooks, I had downloaded and installed Anaconda from http://continuum.io/downloads. There was a problem in the installation (either because it was 32-bit or 64-bit — a detail I can't remember) which I solved but uninstalling my first attempt and installing the other version. Then I went about creating my notebooks with some practice problems.

Currently I can run `ipython notebook` in the command prompt and the notebooks run perfectly well. But the there's no mention of whether the system is 32-bit or 64-bit in the tree of notebooks (or in the tabs nearby).

I would usually sort such issues using the command prompt. But the commands `conda --version` and `ipython --version` just yield the respective version numbers and not the information I am looking for.

My operating system is `Win7x64` but that hasn't prevented me from installing 32-bit softwares in past.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`conda info` has this information. If you need to access it programmatically, use `conda info --json`.

Answer (score 7):

For CentOS 6.7 and miniconda2:

Type `python` and enter these commands:

```
import platform
print platform.architecture()
```

In my case, it gives:

```
('32bit', '')
```

Comment: Great answer! This is really the best answer so far. Very definitive and can be use programtically easily. Not sure why it is getting -ve vote!

Answer (score 2):

Open a standard python console, and in the header it should tell you

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks... that solves it! As a side question how to tackle this issue if Anaconda is not the system Python?

Comment: Check your environment variables, and which python is in your PATH.  Adding/Removing the python directory (or renaming the exe) in the PATH can change the _system_ python.

Comment: "what does it mean? "        Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bi
t (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score -2):

conda --v. It displays the Conda version

Comment: Sorry, we're looking for 32 bit vs 64 bit, not the conda version.